# Capture modified DOM content of completed form

Tags: jquery, html, forms, dom

I am trying to capture the modified HTML of a form to save it for later use. I ideally would like a string that have "checked" and "selected" attributes on radio button/ dropdowns that the user has selected. I am using jQuery and I thought I could do a simple $('form').html() on the form and it would return me the form HTML with the new user inputed values, but it returns me the original HTML with no user input.

How can I create a string of HTML from the filled out form that reflects the user's changes?

Comment: This does not sound like a very good idea. Why do you want to do this?

Comment: Did you try jquery. Serialize()?

Comment: @Tomalak The premise is that the user can take multiple surveys at the same time and can switch between them. I would like to store the HTML of the form as a variable to I can easily recreate it. Also, the form is dynamic, so the number of fields can change.
@Eric Yes, I've thought of Serialize, but it does not give me information on what type of elements I need to recreate, just the name/values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought I'd take a wack at this just for educational purposes...
You could bind all appropriate events to actually edit the DOM:

http://jsfiddle.net/jkj4h/

Comment: Thanks, I think this approach should work. I am just going to add some more listeners for the other input types in the form.

Do you know why the DOM does not change when a user inputs something. You would think that it would change.